# Xpath query start from today

Tags: xml, date, xpath, time

What is the best solution for XPath query to select only data which has `<mdate>` field from today and after

This is an example of the XML

```
<table>
  <title>one subject</title>
  <mdate>2014-05-14T00:00:00+03:00</mdate>
</table>
<table>
  <title>two subject</title>
  <mdate>2014-05-22T00:00:00+03:00</mdata>
</table>
<table>
  <title>3rd subject</title>
  <mdate>2014-05-23T00:00:00+03:00</mdate>
</table>
```

So I need XPath to get only (two subject & 3rd subject)

Comment: Note that your example XML has multiple root elements and is thus not well-formed.

Comment: See XPath 2.0's [op:dateTime-greater-than](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-dateTime-greater-than) and [op:dateTime-equal](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-dateTime-equal).

Comment: XPath 2.0 is best, because it has support for date types. If you are limited to XPath 1.0 it's quite complex, since you will have to deal with days in month, time zones, leap years, etc. If you consider only the date its a bit simpler: you can use the string before the `T`, separate its components and use them to calculate the date.